# After load data: all segments of datasource are _not_ available

Tags: druid

I'm new to apache druid and trying to get my first datasource. For this I'm using the example 'wikipedia' data set.

The task for 'load data' succeeds, but the afterwards the (22) segements of the datasource 'wikipedia' *is published* but **not** *available*. Hence there is no way to use it.

What I'm missing here? Is there an addional log to get more information about the problem?

Answer (score 0):

I also asked this question at the [druid google group](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/druid-user/q-AHMlox53o), and because of this I now know the answer: druid 0.16.0 can only be used with Java 8. I tried to use Java 11 and this fails.